# Receiving uneven results from Serial Port in C#

Tags: c#, c++, serial-port

I have 2 GUI applications, one in C++ and one in C#.
The applications are the same and there is a function that writes and reads from COM port.
When I run my C++ app I receive the right result from the Serial.Read which is a buffer with 24 bytes.
But when I run my C# app I receive uneven results:
* Just 1 byte buffer if I don`t put sleep between write and read.
* Different sizes if I do put sleep between write and read (between 10-22 bytes).

What could be the reason for that?

My C++ code:

```
serial.write(&c, 1, &written);
serial.read(read_buf, read_len, &received); // received = 24
```

My C# code:

```
serial.Write(temp_char, 0, 1);
received = serial.Read(read_buff, 0,read_len); // received = 1
```

C# with sleep:

```
serial.Write(temp_char, 0, 1);
Thread.Sleep(100);
received = serial.Read(read_buff, 0,read_len); // received = (10~22)
```

Answer (score 0):

Serial ports just give a stream of bytes, they don't know how you've written blocks of data to them. When you call read, the bytes that have been received are returned, if that isn't a complete message you need to call read repeatedly until you have the whole message.

You need to define a protocol to indicate message boundaries, this could be a special character (e.g. a new line in a text based protocol) or you can prefix your messages with a length.

Comment: I made a loop with the read function and it solved the problem.
Thanks you !